# Server certificate Invalid or Not present

Tags: delphi, tls1.2, delphi-10.3-rio, tls1.3

I am using NetHTTPRequest1() at a Delphi App which is doing a get request which works on Windows 10 but not on windows 7 I also tried to enable tls1.0, tls1.2, tls1.3 but it didn't seem to work. Any Ideas about what am I doing wrong?  The App is written with Embarcadero Delphi 10.3.

Comment: Win7 does not support TLS1.3, and TLS1.1, and TLS1.2 has to be explicitly enabled in registry. If your server uses 1.3 and does not have some fallback certificate, TNetHTTPRequest will not work. Indy, however might work, because it uses third party libraries, and does not depend on system.