# WIndows succeeding, Android failing second attempts to connect with Server Certificate Invalid or not present error

Tags: android, windows, rest, http, c++builder

Using C++Builder, I need to create a small app that gets some info from a PHP file on a remote site.

I have a `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest` and `TRESTResponse` that are properly setup.

Compiled under Windows 32-bit, I can repeatedly execute the function below and get data back.

However, compiled for Android 32-bit, the code below works ONLY the first time, returning data from the server. Any subsequent button clicks to reenter the function causes a generated error:

> Server Certificate Invalid or not present

There is a related post at [Server certificate Invalid or Not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615816/), but it is of no help.

So, on Windows, this simple code works fine, again and again, but works only once on Android before failing.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    RESTRequest1->Resource = "";
    RESTRequest1->Method = TRESTRequestMethod::rmPOST;
    RESTRequest1->Response = RESTResponse1;
    RESTRequest1->Response->ContentType = "application/json";
    RESTRequest1->Response->ContentEncoding="UTF-8";
    RESTRequest1->Execute();
    
    Memo1->Lines->Add(RESTResponse1->Content);
```

Not sure how to get around this error.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately, Embarcadero does not care.  I reported this as well as sending all the information they need to track down the problem, but they did not spend any time solving it.  In fact, I told them that I was ready to buy if they could figure out the problem, but they totally dropped the ball, and I'm not going to spend that kind of money on thier C++ edition if they can't fix this.

Comment: I'm sad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same problem. I was able to work around it by creating a new TRestClient object dynamically each time that I need to do a request and assign the client of that request to the newly created TRestClient object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).